# Unable to locate element exception

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

The exception

> "{"Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"// > div[@class='item-content'][3]\"}"}"

The code

```
public static  void Main ()
{
    Login_FAM lgn = new Login_FAM();
    Demat_Acount prg = new Demat_Acount();
    lgn.Login();
    prg.DematAdd();
}
```

// login.cs file //
  public  FirefoxDriver driver ;

```
    public Login_FAM()
    {
        driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
public void Login()
{
    driver.Url = "http://180.211.114.147:97//Account/Login";

    var usernameF = driver.FindElementById("UserName");
    var passwdF = driver.FindElementById("Password");
    var loginB = driver.FindElementById("btnLogin");

    usernameF.SendKeys("harsh");
    passwdF.SendKeys("harsh123");
    loginB.Submit();
    // Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

//demat_acount.cs file //

public FirefoxDriver driver;

```
    public Demat_Acount()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

public void DematAdd()
{        
    IWebElement pro = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("// div[@class='item-content'][3]"));
    pro.Click();

    if(pro != null)
    {
        pro.Click();
    }
}
```

below is my HTML Code

```
<ul class="main-navigation-menu ng-scope" ng-controller="menuctrl">
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="active">
    <a ui-sref="app.dashboard" href="#/app/dashboard">
      <div class="item-content" style="padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px">
        <div class="item-media">
          <i style="font-size:20px" class="icon-Dashboard"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-inner">
          <span class="title ng-scope">Dashboard</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="app.familydashboard" href="#/app/FamilyDashboard">
      <div class="item-content" style="padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px">
        <div class="item-media">
          <i style="font-size:20px" class="icon-FamilyDashboard"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-inner">
          <span class="title ng-scope">Family Dashboard</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="open">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">`enter code here`
      <div class="item-content" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 5px">
        <div class="item-media">
          <i style="font-size:20px" class="icon-Profile2"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-inner">
          <span class="title"> Profile </span>
          <i class="icon-arrow" style="margin-top: 3px"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
      <li>
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="app.demataccount" href="#/app/DematAccount">Demat Account</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="app.familyassociation"href="#/app/FamilyMemberAssociation">Family Association</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And FYI i have executed same code without creating methods and objects and that is working but crating method and objects it doesn't working

Comment: Please share the relevant html

Comment: i have specified html code on above. so kindly review the code

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver could not find the element as your element is embedded in another div tag. Make sure your XPath is correct. Validate it using firepath. I'm new to automation, if I get this error, I'll verify my XPath.

Try changing XPath to

```
// div[@class='item-content'][3]/div/i
```

I'm not sure whether this might solve your problem or not, but trying to help. Make sure the element exists or put a wait until the element is visible.

Comment: problem has been solved.. because of i have defined firefox driver in both login and demat_acount.cs file that was creating 2 new object of firefox driver and because of that second demat acount browser object wouldn't be able to find the element and thrown error.. solution :  in demat_acount.cs file mention this...
    demat aFirefoxDriver driver;                                                                          public Demat_Acount()
        {     driver = Login_FAM.driver;       }  correct : driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class='item-content'])[position()=3]"));